# Virtual Hosts Apache Blank page Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5.1

I am trying to set up an existing *laravel 5.1* project with a virtual host on an ubuntu apache server, I have configured the vhosts file accordingly and have done the following commands

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.dev/public
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

to give permissions to the my folder directories. When I go to my URL (e.g `example.dev`)

Every time I try load the server I get a blank page. After looking at the error.log in the apache2 log files I see this

`[Mon Jan 04 20:24:09.072782 2016] [:error] [pid 6002] [client 127.0.0.1:51627] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/example.dev/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:13350\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13288): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13051): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13147): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3 /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12864): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#4 /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(12835): Illuminate\\Log\\Writer->writeLog('error', Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#5 /var/www/example.dev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foun in /var/www/example.dev/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php on line 13350`

Any ideas , All I am trying to achieve is my own virtual host 'example.dev' by following this guide

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Here is almost my `vhosts.conf` settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@pcpal.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/pcpal.dev/public
    ServerName pcpal.dev
    ServerAlias pcpal.dev

    <Directory /var/www/pcpal.dev/public >
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: give write permissions to log directory: /var/www/example.dev/storage/logs/

Comment: do you mind providing the correct terminal command? so i get it correct tbe first time ?

Comment: sudo chmod 777 /var/www/example.dev/storage/logs/

Comment: I did this, and it feels like I am getting somewhere. Although when I try load the page, all I get is 2 x "Whoops looks like something went wrong!" Thanks for your help

Comment: After enabling debug I recieve this error 

No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

Comment: Check if `mod_php` is installed.